# CiviCRM report by address

Tags: 7, civicrm

Is there a way to pull a CiviCRM report that compiles all donations from matching addresses?

Whether or not the people at the matching addresses are formally part of a household -- kind of like the mailing option that merges matching addresses for a mailing export to prevent double mailings.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly the  [Aggregate Household Contribution Report](https://civicrm.org/extensions/aggregate-household-contributions-report) is what you are looking for.  If that is not sufficient, it may provide a good basis for a custom report.

Comment: Thanks, it's not exactly but I may try to use it as a basis for a modification.

Answer (score 2):

This [Display Related Contributions](https://civicrm.org/extensions/display-related-contributions) extension might also be of interest.